# Is there a list of URL schemes?

Tags: url, uri, urn

Is there a list of (all, non-custom) URL schemes?

I thought that I just needed to search on google to find tons of answers, but it's probably wrong my (naive) question.

If so, I will settle the (*usual*) most important:
`file://`, `ftp://`, `http://`, `https://`, `mailto:`, `news:`, `telnet://`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes** ([XML](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xml), [XHTML](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml), [CSV](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes-1.csv), [plain text](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.txt))

It lists all registered (per [RFC 7595](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7595)) URI schemes.

Comment: the files are not helpful really since they do not clearly specify the format. they merely define name of a template and the template itself is defined in plain text file.