# For REST APIs, are URLs meant to be case insensitive?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, web, w3c, api-design

I was reading the [W3C URL Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/url-1/#refsRFC3986) and I noticed that there is nothing explicitly mentioned about this.

**Experiments**

So what I tried in `curl` was

`www.google.com`

and then

`www.GOOGLE.com`

and these returned the same document. So I thought maybe google owns all variations on its domain name, so I tried other sites and I get mixed results.

So I mixed the case on the URL Specification and it seems to allow mixed case.

**Applying this to REST API Design**

So when applying this to REST API design, sometimes we use the notion of an identifier to return a specific resource from the server. E.g.

In `https://localhost:8080/contacts/MYSELF`, `MYSELF` would be the typical identifier

Based on those previous experiences, the case of `MYSELF` should not matter. But what if I wanted strict validation on the identifier?

Sure, you can go against the spec and do this in the application; but what is the appropriate thing to do in this case?

So back to the subject. **Are URLs meant to be case insensitive?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### General URI syntax

In the general URI syntax (as defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), which is currently the [Internet Standard for URIs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/std66)), only **two components are case-insensitive:**

- [Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1):

  > […] schemes are case-insensitive […]
- [Host](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2):

  > The host subcomponent is case-insensitive.

And the letters in percent-encoding triplets (i.e., `a`-`f`, `A`-`F`) are case-insensitive, too.

Everything else is case-sensitive.

However, [URI schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42289198/1591669) can overwrite this for their URIs (see [Case Normalization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.2.1)).

#### HTTP(S) URIs

In the case of HTTP(S) URIs, the spec doesn’t make any other components case-insensitive (it [restates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2.3) that scheme and host are case-insensitive).

That means the following HTTP URIs are **equivalent**:

```
http://example.com/foo
HTTP://example.com/foo
http://EXAMPLE.com/foo
http://example.COM/foo
HTTP://EXAMPLE.COM/foo
htTp://exAMPlE.cOm/foo
```

(Best practice is to normalize scheme and host to lowercase.)

And these are **not equivalent**:

```
http://example.com/foo?bar#baz
http://example.com/fOo?bar#baz
http://example.com/foo?bAr#baz
http://example.com/foo?bar#bAz
http://example.com/FOO?BAR#BAZ
```

Answer (score 2):

Domains are case-insensitive. You don't need to buy every variation, because getting the domain gives you every variation.

There is no specification that says that the 'path' part of a url has to be a particular case. Paths are *not* case insensitive though, so accessing `/foo` and `/FOO` on the same domain *may* yield different resources.

Answer (score 2):

According to W3 specification -

> URLs in general are **case-sensitive** (with the exception of machine
>   names). There may be URLs, or parts of URLs, where case doesn't
>   matter, but identifying these may not be easy. Users should always
>   consider that URLs are case-sensitive.

Source:- https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html