# How to create case-sensitive Uri in C#?

Tags: c#, uri

I need to connect to an API where the services URLs are case sensitive. For example, `https://api-ABC.domain.com` is different from `https://api-abc.domain.com`.

However, every time I create a new `Uri` object in C#, it converts the link to all lower case.

Here is my code:

```
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://api-{caseSensitiveAppId}.domain.com/v2/", UriKind.Absolute);
```

How can I create a `Uri` object that is case sensitive?

Comment: Generally accessing non-compliant resources (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375293/for-rest-apis-are-urls-meant-to-be-case-insensitive) is not supported... I'm pretty sure you need to drop to SSLStream level (or lower) and use your own name resolution outside regular DNS servers.

Comment: In C#, the Uri class normalizes the URI which generally includes converting the scheme and host to lowercase. This is done to comply with the RFC 3986 specification, which states that these components are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

To create a case sensitive Uri in C# you can use the UriBuilder class instead of the Uri class.

```
var builder = new UriBuilder();
builder.Scheme = "https";
builder.Host = $"api-{caseSensativeAppId}.domain.com"; 
builder.Path = "v2/";
```

Comment: HttpClient uses `Uri`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this solution would work for you:

1. get the IP address from DNS by case sensitive host name
2. use the received IP address in the URI instead of the original host name

Below is a very simple example to illustrate this idea

```
var hostName = "api-ABC.domain.com";
var uriStr = "https://{0}/v2/";
var ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName).First();
var uri = new Uri(string.Format(uriStr, ip), UriKind.Absolute);

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var httpMsg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
httpMsg.Headers.Add("Host", hostName);
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpMsg);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```